# Want to make an URDF starting from a robot .STL

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

I want to make an URDF from a Staubli TX2-140. I have the .STL of the all arm. Does someone know how to separate it to get individual links .STL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just open it with any graphics tool (Blender gets the job done, but also FreeCad is an option), select each link's point cloud and save them as separate `.stl` files.

**This is of course not perfect and very error prone!** If you are building a `urdf` robot model I would suggest using an automated export tool on a `.step`/`.cad` file for the best results. There are plenty of options, for these tools, just search online.

In this way you have already the link groups assemblies and hopefully even materials to export mass values and inertia tensors.

A later step is to get the built `.urdf` and converting to `.xacro` for better extensibility with `Gazebo` and other ROS tools.

Comment: Also, when you get to needing inertial properties for Gazebo, I found FreeCad especially helpful for specifying non 1.0 density bodies. The meshlab tutorial they provide will assume a density of 1 kg/m^3 (I think). https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28772/meshlab-calculate-moments-of-inertia-not-assuming-density-of-1/

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a way to convert .STL or .STEP files to urdf. The best I've found so far was to use onshape or gazebo and recreate the model.

"There are plenty of options, for these tools, just search online." Searching the Internet brings back this post. Care to give specifics?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Cal. I'm afraid that on Stack exchange *answers* need to  answer the question. If you have a related question, it should be asked as a new question (ideally referencing this one). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).